# Validating dates with ZOD & React | start date < end date

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, tsx, zod

I'm creating a form where a user can add a vacation to his vacations app.
I use zod as validation.
The rule is - Start date cannot be in the past, and end date cannot be the same date or before the start date.
I have tried to add a refine method to endDate, but I cannot access startDate's value.
Any ideas how to make that validation happen?

**note**
There is a basic validation in my Vacation.ts -

```
 this.startDate =
  startDate < new Date()
    ? (() => {
        throw new Error("Start date cannot be earlier than today.");
      })()
    : startDate;
this.endDate =
  endDate < startDate
    ? (() => {
        throw new Error("End date cannot be earlier than start date.");
      })()
    : endDate;
```

BUT I want extra validation in the form itself before submitting, using onBlur so it'll be dynamic and change when the user chooses the date.

I'm also thinking about using MUI's range date picker. Not sure if that will solve anything.

this is my code:

```
function AddVacation(): JSX.Element {
let allVacations: Vacation[] = [];
type FormData = {
    // id: number,
    destination: string,
    startDate: Date,
    endDate: Date,
    vacDesc: string,
    vacPrice: number,
    vacImg: string,
  }
  // This will be the schema for the form, it'll be used to validate the form when submitting.
  //z.coerce.date() is used to convert the string to a date object.
  const schema: ZodType<FormData> = z.object({
    destination: z.string().min(2, {message: 'Destination must have at least 2 characters'}).nonempty(),
    startDate: z.coerce.date().refine((data) => data > new Date(), {message: 'Start date must be in the future'}),
    endDate: z.coerce.date(),
    vacDesc: z.string().min(2).nonempty(),
    vacPrice: z.number().positive().max(1000),
    vacImg: z.string().nonempty()
  })
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { register, handleSubmit, trigger ,formState: { errors } } = useForm<FormData>({resolver: zodResolver(schema)});
  const onSubmit = (data: FormData) => {
        console.log("submitting...")
        console.log(errors);
        const newVacation = new Vacation(data.destination, data.startDate, data.endDate, data.vacDesc, data.vacPrice, data.vacImg);
        allVacations.push(newVacation);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(`allVacations: ${allVacations}`)
        navigate("/vacationList")
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `.refine` to the schema itself and pass `endDate` in the `path` to specify that `endDate` is the thing causing the error and it's not just a generic error on the form itself.

(I've removed the extra fields for simplicity in this example, and set the year to `2100` to make this example valid for a while)

```js
import { z, ZodType } from "zod";

type FormData = {
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
};
// This will be the schema for the form, it'll be used to validate the form when submitting.
//z.coerce.date() is used to convert the string to a date object.
const schema: ZodType<FormData> = z
  .object({
    startDate: z.coerce.date().refine((data) => data > new Date(), { message: "Start date must be in the future" }),
    endDate: z.coerce.date(),
  })
  .refine((data) => data.endDate > data.startDate, {
    message: "End date cannot be earlier than start date.",
    path: ["endDate"],
  });
```

With these tests, the code works

```js
const shouldPass = schema.safeParse({
  startDate: "2100-01-01",
  endDate: "2100-01-02",
});
console.log(shouldPass.success); // true
if (shouldPass.success) {
  console.log(shouldPass.data); 
  /*
  {
    "startDate": 2100-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,
    "endDate": 2100-01-02T00:00:00.000Z
  }
  */
} else {
  console.log(shouldPass.error); // doesn't get here
}

const shouldFail = schema.safeParse({
  startDate: "2100-01-02",
  endDate: "2100-01-01",
});
console.log(shouldFail.success); // false
if (shouldFail.success) {
  console.log(shouldFail.data); // doesn't get here
} else {
  console.log(shouldFail.error);
  /*
  {
    "code": "custom",
    "message": "End date cannot be earlier than start date.",
    "path": [
      "endDate"
    ]
  }
  */
}
```

Comment: @ Samathingamajig - thanks' will check that
Does inserting the refine after endDate:z.coerce.date(), )}.refine any making any difference than inserting the refine right after .date().refine?
becuase when trying the latter - I couldnt get the value from startDate

Comment: Also, it validates only upon submitting although having onBlur and trigger on the date field itself.
<TextField type="date" {...register("endDate")} error={!!errors.endDate} helperText={errors.endDate?.message}
                onBlur={() => trigger('endDate')}/>